# In a resource manager, how do I handle a resource containing other resources?

Tags: resource-management

I have a resource manager, handling the usual resource loading, unloading etc. With resources such an images and meshes, there is no problem. However, what do I do when I have a resource containing other resources? For example, `spriteFont` contains reference to a sprite and a letter description.

Should that sprite be added to resource manager, or should my `spriteFont` be the only owner of that resource?

Comment: What can be the problem if you add SpriteFont too?
"my spriteFont must be the only owner of that resource" what do you mean by owner?

Comment: Owner means nobody references to that sprite even resource manager, nobody knows about it's existence. It' helps reduce reference between classes, SpriteFont does not require resource manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fonts own the images that represent their fonts. I see no reason to add the image to the general pool of resources. The resource manager doesn't even need to know about it. I use the same routines for loading the image, but it's loaded into the font object. Nothing other than the fonts will use that image.